# Unauthorizing a Google API

Tags: google-api

In my C# desktop app, I authorize the use of a Google API using:

```
credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets, Scopes, "user", CancellationToken.None);
```

Is there an API that can unauthorize it?

Answer (score 0):

This authorization is only for an hour or so and after that the generated access token expires.